# Value to access across the project in console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, azure-keyvault

I have a console application solution having multiple projects like class library etc. added to this. I have stored my username/password in Azure keyvault and almost all projects under the solution are using it. Every time I am hitting vault to get the username/password. For one execution I want to hit the keyvault only once and share the username/password across the project under the solution for single execution.

Comment: I suggest that you use a singleton to work with the shared values. For-example, you may use a static class with public static properties in one of the class libraries whose values are set once you have retrieved the values from the Azure keyvault and then can be accessed by any other method / class without going to the keyvault to fetch the values again by simply getting the static variable values

Comment: It is good when you have a single class/project. How to pass value from project like one class library to another class library, not even single time, it may be multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the credentials should not be a part of every method that needs the credentials. You are mixing concerns here which is a bad practice. Imagine at some point you don't want to use the Azure Keyvauld anymore, then you have to go into way too many classes and methods to update your code.

Another problem with this is coming up if you're doing unit tests. You shouldn't need to make calls to azure to test methods in your class library projects.

The way I would do it is to retrieve the credentials in one location (e.g. in the console application when it's starting up) and pass the credentials as parameters into your methods or class constructors whenever they are required.

Comment: I am using the same thing. I have one central method to collect value based on key [passig key as a parameter] and calling that method from wherever I need values.

Comment: My main problem is that how can I share same value from project to project like what we have session in asp.net.

Comment: You are calling your other projects from your console application, right? Then you can simply pass in the credentials into the constructor/method as a parameter. If the projects are running separately then you'll have to look into something like redis cache.